# How do I copy objects of different classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :singer, :year, :production
end
```

and:

```
class SongsCopy < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :singer, :year
end
```

What is the most simple way to copy attributes from `A(Song)` to `B(SongsCopy)` *while* creating `B`, remembering `SongsCopy` has no attribute `:production`?

Comment: changed it to 'most simple';]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimal way would be to do it inside the database with a bit of SQL:

```
insert into songs_copies (title, singer, year)
select title, singer, year
from songs
where ...
```

But if you have a bunch of callbacks and such that you need to run then you could do something like this:

```
song = some_song_that_you_already_have
copy = SongsCopy.create(song.attributes.except('id', 'production'))
```

or:

```
copy = SongsCopy.create(song.attributes.slice('title', 'singer', 'year'))
```

Comment: should i overwrite ':create' method, or is Rails going to know what i mean passing 'song.attributes....'?

Comment: `song.attributes` returns a Hash like any other Hash, there's no need for anything special when passing a Hash to `create`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest possibility (and certainly not preferred), but the easiest would be:

```
class SongsCopy < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(args = nil)
    if args.is_a? Song
      super
      self.title = song.title
      self.singer = song.singer
      self.year = song.year
    else
      super(args)
    end
  end
end

a = Song
b = SongsCopy.new(a)
```

I'm sure there's another way to do this, but the above should work.

Comment: Overriding ActiveRecord's `initialize` generally doesn't work out that well.